# SQL Server FOR DELETE trigger is not working on inner join with cascading keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

I have a PK/FK table below called Parent and Child. The Parent when deleted will cascade and delete the children. When the Child is deleted first, the trigger should run - shouldn't it? I can't get my join to work and I am assuming the Parent table row is already gone. How can I accomplish this? I already added this to the parent table too.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [ChildDelete]
ON [Child]
FOR DELETE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO StreamingJob(EventId, GameId, [Type], StreamingId)
        SELECT d.EventId, NULL, 3, g.StreamingId 
        FROM [Parent] g 
        INNER JOIN Deleted d ON g.Id = d.Id
        WHERE g.StreamingId IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: you'll need to write instead of trigger. you can check this medium post by Lukas Sinkus. https://medium.com/@lukassinkus/sql-server-combination-of-cascade-deletes-and-triggers-might-not-work-in-the-order-you-expect-them-79f16f061aa8

Comment: I have, but I want to cascade on the table, which you cant with INSTEAD

Comment: maybe its executing but didn't find the data. check this discussion https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic578169-361-1.aspx

Comment: It doesnt work on parent either, is there no way to do this?  Does a trigger happen after the cascades and deletions of both tables?